# How to get clickable tooltips for custom Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been through pages of Google results and I guess I'm either just crazy or I'm just not using the right terms.  I'm trying to figure out how to show this tooltip when you click on a marker.  I keep seeing it consistently on web sites.  Does anyone have ideas on what I should be googling?

It looks like on this web page: http://onemarco.com/examples/Tooltip_v2/ it's a `GInfoWindowTab`, but that seems to be with Google Maps API v2, not v3.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called an [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) in the documentation.

There are a couple of examples in the [Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows), and some cuatom versions available (if you don't like the new square corners in the built in infoWindow)